# How could I read a properties file and insert data into XML file?

Tags: xml, hibernate, jakarta-ee, properties

I have a properties file with data to connect with database. Also, I have a hibernate config file. I would like to config the hibernate file with properties from properties file. How could I read the properties and insert them into XML file? I can read the properties via System.getProperty(name).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this should be a good start:

```
File xmlfile = null;
File propertiesfile = null;
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new FileReader(propertiesfile));

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document parse = db.parse(xmlfile);
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(parse);
Node root = domSource.getNode();
for (Object key : p.keySet()) {
    String sKey = "" + key;
    root.setTextContent(root.getTextContent()+sKey + "=" + p.getProperty(sKey));
}
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.transform(domSource, new StreamResult(xmlfile));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have to do this repeatedly, I'd use this ancient programming technique:

- Open properties file
- Highlight a property in properties file
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>
- Open hibernate config xml file
- Locate insert carat at place of property value
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>

Comment: Correct, but useless --- Oh even not correct: this is not configuration

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the documentation right, it should be work out of the box:

Hibernate reference

[3.7. XML configuration file](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-xmlconfig)

> An alternative approach to configuration is to specify a full
>   configuration in a file named hibernate.cfg.xml. This file can be used
>   as a replacement for the hibernate.properties  file or, if both are
>   present, to override properties.

So you only need the hibernate properties file and the hibernate.cfg.xml. If you do not set the values in hibernate.cfg.xml, then they are taken from the properties file. -- *I did not proved that, but that is the way I understand the documentation.*

Comment: I have the xml file, but data from database, user and password I would like to read it from properties file and load it in XML file

Comment: @Jose Hdez: yes that is what I am talking about: do not add this 3 properties to the `hibernate.cfg.xml`, instead put it in the `hibernate.properties` file